# Table caption remove from numbering

Tags: tables, captions, numbering

In the specond chapter there is a multi page table, thus I am using `longtable`. And I do not want any caption, caption label.

In the fifth chapter there is a simple table, and it has caption and caption label as well. The problem is that the its caption label number is 2, I want it to be 1, so the multi page table should not count.

I am using `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` because I do not want chapter label number in the caption.

**Code**

The first table has about 50-60 rows, the second table has 6 rows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lp{0.70\textwidth}}
ab & ab \\ab & ab \\ab & ab \\ab & ab
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{\normalfont{aaa}}
\label{tab:sp}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
aa  & 222 & 222 & 22  & 22  \\
bb  & 333 & 333 & 33  & 33  \\
cc  & 444 & 444 & 44  & 44  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Currently how it looks**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`longtable` increment `table` counter regardless that it has not contain a caption. That you will get what you like, just add to its preamble

```
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\endlastfoot
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lp{0.70\textwidth}}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}   % <---
\endlastfoot
ab & ab \\
ab & ab \\
ab & ab \\
ab & ab
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:sp}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
aa  & 222 & 222 & 22  & 22  \\
bb  & 333 & 333 & 33  & 33  \\
cc  & 444 & 444 & 44  & 44  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum :**
If you can (or willing) to use `longtblr` of `tabularray` package instead of `longtable`, than the solution can be:

**Edit:**
I'm very sorry that I didn't check original answer. I overlooked that `longtblr` works as you like only if it not span several page. Now this "malfunction" is corrected and showed possible solution works as desired (i.e. as I understood now that it should):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}    % Removes a caption
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}    % Removes a caption on subsequent pages
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}{}   % Removes text denoting continuation on next page
\begin{longtblr}[
entry = \empty
                ]{colspec={l p{0.70\textwidth}}}
ab & \lipsum[1] \\
cd & \lipsum[2] \\
ef & \lipsum[3] \\
gh & \lipsum[4]
\end{longtblr}

\endgroup

\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I am using `longtblr` , then at the buttom of the page `Continued on next page`, and at next page top `Table 0 (Continued)`, how could I get rid of them?

Comment: @mala97, See addendum to answer.